# How to measure IIS application performance over time

Tags: iis

My team is responsible for monitoring the performance of our custom application infrastructure. On the SQL side of life, there are lots of great tools to monitor performance, bottlenecks, and changes in performance over time. I'd love to find a tool for Microsoft IIS that shows me broad metrics (# of hits over a period of time), details (# of hits for a particular path over a period of time), and tools to show me changes in application performance for particular paths over time. Does anyone have a tool for this that they prefer?

Comment: Things like AppDynamics are rather famous, but none of them are cheap and easy.

Answer (score 1):

You need application performance monitoring (APM). Insight into where exactly requests are spending time in the application is necessary, which implies instrumentation of the app. As this can be a significant project, there is a decision to be made of build vs buy.

Build would be integrating various open source components. Check out [OpenAPM landscape](https://openapm.io/landscape) for a functionality matrix of what some of these can do.  For example, App Metrics .NET instrumentation, indexed in Elasticsearch, with Grafana dashboards and Bosun alerts. Pick and choose, this is à la carte.

Then you have buy. The market is mature enough that this is a category of software, see APM listings in [G2](https://www.g2.com/categories/application-performance-monitoring-apm) or [Capterra](https://www.capterra.com/application-performance-management-software/). All in on Microsoft there is [Application Insights](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/web-monitor-performance). Or specialist products in this space include Dynatrace, AppDynamics, or New Relic. These probably have some expense, but are integrated platforms with support.

Either way, likely get a platform you can also send traditional host and network monitoring data to. Just don't expect host CPU and interface dropped packets to solve all your performance problems.